# Do I need to use transaction when reading data after write?

Tags: node.js, database, postgresql, transactions

I have a Node.js web app with a route that marks some entity as deleted - flipping boolean field in a database. This route returns that entity. Right now I have code that looks like this:

```
UPDATE entity SET is_deleted=true WHERE entity.id = ?
SELECT * FROM entity WHERE entity.id = ?
```

For the moment I can't use RETURNING statement for other reasons.
So I got in the argument with colleague, I think that putting both UPDATE and SELECT inside transaction is unnecessary, because we are not doing anything significant with data, just returning it. As a user of the app I would expect that data that is returned is as fresh as possible, meaning that I would get same results on page refresh.

My question is, what is the best practice regarding reading data after write? Do you always wrap reading with writing inside transaction? Or it depends?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, for performance reasons you want to keep your transactions as small and quick as possible. This will minimize the chance to have potential locks and deadlocks that could bring your application to its knees. As such, unless there is a very good reason to do so, keep your select statements outside of the transaction. This is specially important if your need to execute a long running select statement. By putting the select inside the transaction, you keep the update locks much longer than needed.